# Integrating CAD Cam image as iframe in webcenter portal application

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper, webcenter

we have to integrate 3D image into our portal application as an iframe inline to our pages

Currently we  used  inline frame  which is opening as new window of browser

```
<af:inlineFrame id="if1" source="<Some SRC>" sizing="preferred"/>
```

Does anyone know of the right way to show that iframe inline to our portal page.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, that should be the right way to create an iframe on the current page.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/apirefs.1111/e12419/tagdoc/af_inlineFrame.html

There must be something else going on. Is the target web application (hosting the 3D image) by any chance using frame busting to avoid being shown inside an iframe?
If it's ADF, see: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/b31973/ap_config.htm#BABDHGEJ